# How to read data from db2 using jdbc connection?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to fetch the data from db2 using

```
df= spark.read.format(“jdbc”).option(“user”,”user”).option(“password”,”password”)\
.option(“driver”, “com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver”)\
.option(“url”,”jdbc:db2://url:<port>/<DB>”)\
.option(“query”, query)\
.load()
```

In my local in options query function is working but in server it is asking me to use dbtable
when i use dbtable i'm getting sqlsyntax error: sql code =-104 sqlstate =42601 and taking wrong columns

can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AS400** driver to fetch DB2 data using Spark.

Your DB2 URL will look something like this: `jdbc:as400://<DBIPAddress>`

```
val query = "(select * from db.temptable) temp"

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", <YourURL>).option("driver", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").option("dbtable", query).option("user", <Username>).option("password", <Password>).load()
```

Please note that you will need to keep the query format as shown above (*i.e. give an alias to the query*). Hope this resolves your issue.